# Why can you not declare constants in methods with Ruby?

Tags: ruby, constants

Consider the following, StubFoo is a stub of Foo, which I wish to stub out for some tests.

```
class Runner

  def run
      Foo = StubFoo
      foo = Foo.new
      # using Foo...
  end

end
```

This generates the following error message: `Dynamic constant assignment`

Yet, in RSpec I can do the following, which works and is perfectly legal:

```
it "should be an example" do
  Foo = StubFoo
  foo = Foo.new
  foo.to_s.should == "I am stubbed!"
end
```

A few questions regarding this.

- Why does this work with the RSpec test case, but not the method above?
- As far as I'm aware, "it" is just a method within RSpec, yet I'm able to redeclare a constant within the "method".

I'm doing this prior to using a mocking framework for purely wanting to know how mocking, stubbing etc... is different in Ruby. I hear that dynamic languages are easier to mock/stub, and there are guides on the Internet in which simple class reassignment is done as above. From my research, in Ruby it's not possible to declare constants within a method, yet I'm confused as mentioned above.

**Edit**

Right, this is starting to make more sense. I've updated run to be using const_set now.

```
  def run
      old = Foo
      self.class.const_set(:Foo, StubFoo)
      foo = Foo.new
      puts foo.to_s
      self.class.const_set(:Foo, old)
      foo = Foo.new
      puts foo.to_s
  end
```

This generates a warning however, is this what/how mocking frameworks work then in Ruby? Obviously much more elegant and feature full, but do they simply repress this warning?

Answer (score 10):

You can't reassign constants in method definitions using `Constant = value`. You can however reassign them using `const_set`. Basically it's meant to discourage, but not disallow, dynamic constant reassignment.

As to why it works with `it`: Yes, `it` is a method, but you're not defining, you're calling it. The reassignment takes place inside the block which you pass as an argument to `it`.

Blocks inherit the type of the context in which they are created. This means that inside the block, `self.class.name` would be the name of your test class. Therefore, when you define a constant inside the block passed to the `it` method, you're actually defining a constant on your test class.

Comment: @user1735921 An example of what?

Answer (score 2):

Because in your test, you are not defining a method, but rather *calling* `it`.

Ruby detects you are defining a constant in a method, that can be run multiple times, hence the warning. If you call the method more than once, you'll get a `warning: already initialized constant Foo` warning. This is because they're supposed to be constants. (What would happen, for example, if you defined `Foo = Time.now`?)

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error because if `Runner#run` is called, `Foo` will be changed unexpectedly on the caller. For example:

```
class C; end

def add_two_to(x) # this method is defined externally, and you cannot change it.
  C = Class.new {} # error
  x + 2
end

x = C.new
puts add_two_to(5)
y = C.new

x.is_a? y.class # would be false if the code get here
```

The caller of `add_two_to` does not expect `C` to be redefined. It just makes more sense that the last line of the above code will always be true. In your second example, your "method" is not actually a method, but a block. If you run the block twice (which `it` will not do), you will get this error:

```
warning: already initialized constant Q
```

Comment: That's not an error. It's a warning. The program will still run perfectly fine.