# ruby constant destroyed after method terminates?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a class inheriting from ActiveRecord::Base, which has an after_create callback. Inside the callback, I create a constant as shown below:

```
class ClassificationCode < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_create :associate_mongoid

  def associate_mongoid
    class_str = column_field.classify
    klass = Object.const_set class_str, Class.new
    puts "What is this #{klass} and its name #{klass.name}" # What is this SportsField and its name SportsField
    c = klass.new
    c['dynamic_field'] = 'abc'
    c.save
  end
end
```

The item is successfully saved in my mongoid db, so I know this method fully executes. However, that constant ceases to exist outside of that method call. I launch a rails console:

```
> SportsField
NameError: uninitialized constant SportsField

> ClassificationCode::SportsField
NameError: uninitialized constant ClassificationCode::SportsField
```

What happened to the constant? Why doesn't it exist anymore? I reloaded the console several times and still this constant does not exist.

Comment: This may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3409931/why-can-you-not-declare-constants-in-methods-with-ruby

Comment: I tried both Object.const_set and self.class.const_set, regardless of where I set the constant, it simply does not exist after that method call.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a scope issue. You define a constant in your method and then exit that method. Constants are pretty much like any other variable except that you can't reassign them. If you define it in a method, it is not defined outside that method. I think you are misusing the constant here.

Comment: I thought Object.const_set would define the constant at the object level and not as a local variable of this method.

Comment: It is not my understanding: [Ruby doc on const_set](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Module.html#method-i-const_set). The `Object.const_set` just means you call the static method `const_set` from the Object (which happens to be a Module). But it doesn't switch scope or anything.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on how to make this available globally?

Comment: I would not use a constant. If you fear to accidentally overwrite it, I'd look into `attr_reader` but basically it would be either an instance variable `@var` or a class variable `@@var` depending on where and how you plan to use this variable.

Comment: Except you can reassign constants.  The problem is the scope.  Where the class is being created.  The constant still exists, as can be observed by calling `Object.constants.include? :SportsField`.  How are you going to access a class that has a scope of an individual object instantiated on your class?  Is it the right thing to do?  Or can you do something simpler?